# Freelancing in Data Science

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I would like to dive into freelancing in data science but I don't know how to do it, which site I can consult.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is a good fit for this site. Maybe it would get better responses in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/datascience). That said, in some European countries (France, Spain, Germany) you can use [malt](https://www.malt.es/).

Comment: https://www.freelancermap.com/ might be another option

Comment: @noe Okay i see!

Comment: @Sammy thank you!

Comment: It might help to say what skills you have and what kind of work you want to do.

Comment: Hi, Am looking for someone who can help me with data science queries. As am new, I have tonnes of question (concept wise). So, is there anyone who can help with freelance support for data dcience relted queries

Comment: @TheGreat That would Data Science and Cross Validated.

Comment: Yes, I am receiving support from people like you. Am also okay to pay to get some dedicated support

Comment: If you want to pay, then that’s called a master’s degree.